# How to add/insert in EF from arguments passed by jquery ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

How to insert values from the jquery ajax into EF table?

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveScheduleAppointment(string CustName, string schedDate, string _startTime, string _endTime)
    {
     List<SchedAppointment> schedApt = new List<SchedAppointment>();

      using(var db = new DCDBEntities())
        {
         schedApt.Add(new SchedAppointment()
          {                    
           appointmentDate = schedDate,
           customerFullName = "",
           appointmentDescription = "",
           customerPatientId = 0,
           endTime ="",
           startTime = ""
           });
           db.ScheduleAppointments.Add(schedApt);
           db.SaveChanges();
         }
        return View();
    }
```

Im getting this error

> Error 1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet.Add(DentalClinicSystem.Models.ScheduleAppointment)' has some invalid arguments    c:\users\francisco.l.saul\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\dentalclinicsystem\dentalclinicsystem\controllers\schedulecontroller.cs 44  17  DentalClinicSystem

Comment: updated above code .

Comment: how can I insert the list in EF table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `schedApt` so it is a single appointment, not a list:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveScheduleAppointment(string CustName, string schedDate, string _startTime, string _endTime)
    {
      using(var db = new DCDBEntities())
        {
         //Here - use ScheduleAppointment not SchedAppointment
         ScheduleAppointment schedApt = new ScheduleAppointment
          {    
            // You may also need to change your properties to ones in the new class                
           appointmentDate = schedDate,
           customerFullName = "",
           appointmentDescription = "",
           customerPatientId = 0,
           endTime ="",
           startTime = ""
           };

           //Alternatively, you might need to change this bit to a list of SchedAppointment 
           db.ScheduleAppointments.Add(schedApt);
           db.SaveChanges();
         }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: i will try it . .

Comment: same error message Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'DentalClinicSystem.Models.SchedAppointment' to 'DentalClinicSystem.Models.ScheduleAppointment' c:\users\francisco.l.saul\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\dentalclinicsystem\dentalclinicsystem\controllers\schedulecontroller.cs 39 45 DentalClinicSystem

Comment: OK - looks like you're using the wrong class. db.ScheduleAppointments is a list of ScheduleAppointment not of SchedAppointment. I don't know what the differences between your two classes are, but I've made a small tweak which might help.

Comment: salute to you my brother! :)

Comment: question, what if I am going to insert from List<ScheduleAppointment> ?

Comment: You can use the AddRange method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx